# Routing - Reactjs - only first Route works

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I want to create reusable Route component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ITProffesion {
  proffesion: string;
}

export const ITRoleRouter: React.FC<ITProffesion> = ({ proffesion }) => (
  <Route exact path={`/${proffesion}`} key={proffesion}>
    <p>Works {proffesion}</p>
  </Route>
);
```

but when i want to use it - only first Route works - example (only backend works - is's a test I
will download data from api):

```
export const App: React.FC<{}> = () => (

      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <DemoContainer />
          </Route>
          <ITRoleRouter proffesion="backend" />
          <ITRoleRouter proffesion="frontend" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
);
```

What is wrong? Can I use react router in this way?
Thanks,Asia

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that the `Switch` component uses the `path` and `from` props of its children components to check whether there is a route match, which decides what is rendered.

The `ITRoleRouter` component instances don't have these props but are children of the `Switch` component.

Because both `ITRoleRouter` instances don't have these props it will instead match the first instance.

So instead you could do something like this:

```
interface ITProffesion {
  path: string;
  proffesion: string;
}

const ITRoleRouter: React.FC<ITProffesion> = ({ path, proffesion }) => (
  <Route exact path={path} key={proffesion}>
    <p>Works {proffesion}</p>
  </Route>
);

const App: React.FC<{}> = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <DemoContainer />
      </Route>
      <ITRoleRouter path="/backend" proffesion="backend" />
      <ITRoleRouter path="/frontend" proffesion="frontend" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Check out [this Github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5841#issuecomment-355673827) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
> Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

Switch only works with the first level of components directly under it.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fog-ghsu6)